# Groovy AntBuilder file sorting

Tags: ant, groovy

groovy AntBuilder style select sorted files:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder();
def files =   ant.first(count:1){
        sort(){
            fileset(dir:/R:\goagent2/){
                depth  max:0
            }
           // reverse(){ date(); }
            date()
        }
    }*.file;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it with plain Groovy?

```
def oldestFile = new File( /R:\goagent2/ ).listFiles()
                                          .sort { it.lastModified() }
                                          .head()
```